# How to limit memory available to a process?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, process

Let's say I have two processes. One critical and one nice to have process.

Now, let's say the nice to have process starts leaking memory. How can I stop the leaking process from using up all system memory and causing the critical one to crash or slow down?

I would like that the non-critical process simply terminate or throw `std::bad_alloc` when it uses more memory than a certain threshold.

Comment: I guess one way would be to simply have a thread that checks the memory usage and calls `std::terminate` if it exceeds it. Though getting a `std::bad_alloc` on `new` would be a nicer solution which the process at least could try to recover from.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Windows do not support ulimit style restriction, so the next best thing may be write a watchdog program, check process's memory (and/or other resource usage) and terminate them if needed.

As a side note, I would not bet on a program to terminate itself when things already get messed.

See also: [EnumProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [GetProcessWorkingSetSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)